# Read object value in Nestjs problems

Tags: nestjs

I faced with problem to read object in Nestjs

There is the code

```
    @Post()
  @UseInterceptors(
    FileInterceptor('file', {
      storage: diskStorage({
        destination: (req, file, cb) => {
          const userId = req.body.username;
          const usern = req.user;
          console.log(usern);

          const dir = `./public/avatar/${userId}`;
          fs.exists(dir, (exist) => {
            if (!exist) {
              return fs.mkdir(dir, (error) => cb(error, dir));
            }
            return cb(null, dir);
          });
```

console.log(usern) return

```
{
  _id: '6026654c957fe6330a6d54c2',
  status: 'active',
  iat: 1615467122,
  exp: 1615553522
}
```

But If i try to get `req.user._id` an error is appear
**error TS2339: Property '_id' does not exist on type 'User'.**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a TypeScript error, your `User` class appears not to have the attribute `_id`. you should add the attribute in the class.

Comment: req.user  return {
  _id: '6026654c957fe6330a6d54c2',
  status: 'active',
  iat: 1615467122,
  exp: 1615553522
}, but i can't get access to any of this fields. For example req.user.status also get an error.

Comment: The problem is not how your code behaves, it's your code compilation. `req.user` is expected to be of class `User`, so when you ask `req.user._id` it throws an error because the attribute is not present in your class. So change your class to allow compilation.